# How do I configure Ampache to play music in the web interface?

Tags: web-development

I had an ampache server already before and I could play individual songs or playlists on the web interface through the PC speaker.

I have now newly setup an ampache server which I can access with my android app and play music there. However, I fail to get the music to play from the website interface. I can login there and manage playlists. I thought I used to have a "play" button next to each item. That is not there now however.

I am running Ampache v.3.6-Alpha1-DEV.

Any idea on how to configure it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can add tracks or full albums under the "Add" header.  Once you do, they will appear in the form of a list near the top right side of the web application.  At the top of that list there is an option to "Play" but you first have to choose "flashplayer" or "steam" from the drop down just above (also near to the top right).